# LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO IN Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
updated_date  = 08-Jun-2010;
```

I have a query like this

```
select * from asd whre updated_date <= todate('08-Jun-2010', 'dd-MM-yy');
```

but I am not getting any results. it only works if `todate` is 09-Jun-2010...

i.e. my `equalto` operator is not working properly.

why is it like that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Oracle a DATE is a point in time. It always has a time component with a precision to the second. `todate('08-Jun-2010', 'dd-Mon-yyyy')` is in Oracle the same as `todate('08-Jun-2010 00:00:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`. So if you select rows up to that date you won't get any row on that day with a time component not equal to `00:00`.

If you want to select all the rows up to and including `08-JUN-2010`, I would suggest using:

```
< to_date('09-06-2010', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

or

```
<= to_date('08-06-2010 23:59:59', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

**Note** - I corrected your date format: you need to use `MON` if you want to use the abbreviated month name. I would suggest using `MM` instead, so that you won't get error when someone changes its client settings (`NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`). Also prefer the use of `YYYY` instead of `YY`.

Comment: +1 for the reason for using 'MM' instead of "Abbreviated name of month" format.

Comment: This is my working solution: select * from TABLE_NAME where TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < to_date('05-01-2023 10:00:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Answer (score 15):

Check this,

```
select to_date('08-Jun-2010', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual;
```

It is equal to `2010-06-08 00:00:00`. Notice the time.

The `updated_date` has time portion. To include them, please use this query,

```
select * from asd where trunc(updated_date) <= to_date('08-Jun-2010', 'dd-MON-yyyy');
```

The default `TRUNC` function for date parameter will remove the time.

Refer [Trunc](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

Comment: This also works but time is set to 00:00:00: select * from TABLE_NAME where TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < to_date('05-01-2023', 'dd-MM-yyyy') and it's same like select * from TABLE_NAME where TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < to_date('05-01-2023 00:00:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')